# Testing Custom JS with Jasmine and Protractor

Tags: javascript, cookies, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to write Jasmine test code for a custom JS module(?) that cookies return visitors and redirects them to their cookie'd region.

The JS works fine, but it doesn't seem to be recognized by Jasmine / Protractor as those pages don't redirect as they should.

my spec.js file:

```
describe("cookies", function() {
    var bridgepage = ('http://0.0.0.0:4567/');
    var citypage = ('http://0.0.0.0:4567/nyc/');

    // cookied visitors
    it('should redirect to city pages for cookied visitors', function(){
        browser.get(citypage);
        browser.get(bridgepage)
        browser.sleep(1000);
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(citypage);
    })

});
```

folder structure:

```
- source
-- javascripts
---- lib
-- all.js
-- cookies.js // file to test
- spec
-- javascripts
---- helpers
---- supoort
-- spec.js // specs
```

cookies.js file:

```
var cookies = (function() { 

  var utma = $.cookie("__utma");
  var serviceArea = $.cookie('first_visit_service_area')

  var isFirstVisit = function() {
    if (utma == null) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      var utmaArray = utma.split('.');
      var firstVisitTime = utmaArray[2];
      var currentVisitTime = utmaArray[4];
      return (firstVisitTime == currentVisitTime);
    }
  }

[...]

  // Set cookies according to (...)
  // If the user has never visited the site, (...)
  // If the user (...), (...)
  if (utma == null) {
    // user has apparently disabled cookies or blocked google analytics cookies
    return;
  }

  if (window.location.pathname == '/' && serviceArea) { 
    redirectServiceArea(); 
  }

  if (isFirstVisit) { 
    setCookies(); 
  }


}());
```

This my first attempt at writing JS tests, so any help would be much appreciated! :)